# Разместить текст в нужный QLineEdit по нажатию на кнопку "1"

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qtimer

Как в методе `one()` сделать:

- если перед нажатием на кнопку **`1`** фокус был на `lineedit`, то писать `1` в `lineedit` ,
- если фокус был на `lineedit2` и после этого нажатием на кнопку **`1`**, то писать `1` в `lineedit2`?

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore , QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Калькулятор")
        self.resize(450, 200)
        
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("calculator.png"))
        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.grid)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Ответ:")
        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("-")
        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("+")
        self.btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("/")
        self.btn4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("*")
        self.btn5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("1")
        self.btn6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("2")
        self.btn7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("3")
        self.btn8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("4")
        self.btn9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("5")
        self.btn10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("6")
        self.btn11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("7")
        self.btn12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("8")
        self.btn13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("9")
        self.btn14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("0")
        self.btn16 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("C")
        self.btn15 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("**")

        self.lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineedit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 9, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lineedit, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lineedit2, 0 ,1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn1, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn2 , 1 , 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn3 , 2, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn4 , 2, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn15 , 3 , 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn16 ,3 , 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn5 ,4 , 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn6 , 4  ,1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn7 , 5 ,0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn8 , 5 ,1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn9 , 6 ,0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn10, 6 ,1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn11 , 7 ,0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn12, 7 ,1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn13, 8 ,0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn14, 8, 1)

        
        
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.minus)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.plus)
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(self.delen)
        self.btn4.clicked.connect(self.umn)
        self.btn5.clicked.connect(self.one)
        self.btn6.clicked.connect(self.two)
        self.btn7.clicked.connect(self.three)
        self.btn8.clicked.connect(self.four)
        self.btn9.clicked.connect(self.five)
        self.btn10.clicked.connect(self.six)
        self.btn11.clicked.connect(self.seven)
        self.btn12.clicked.connect(self.eight)
        self.btn13.clicked.connect(self.nine)
        self.btn14.clicked.connect(self.zero)
        self.btn16.clicked.connect(self.clear)
        self.btn15.clicked.connect(self.qwe)

        self.btn1.setShortcut("Ctrl+1")
        self.btn2.setShortcut("Ctrl+2")
        self.btn3.setShortcut("Ctrl+3")
        self.btn4.setShortcut("Ctrl+4")
        self.btn16.setShortcut("Ctrl+5")
        self.btn15.setShortcut("Ctrl+6")


    def qwe(self):
        result = int(self.lineedit.text()) ** int(self.lineedit2.text())
        
        self.label.setText(f"Ответ: {result}")

    def minus(self):
        result = int(self.lineedit.text()) - int(self.lineedit2.text())
        
        self.label.setText(f"Ответ: {result}")


    def plus(self):
        result = int(self.lineedit.text()) + int(self.lineedit2.text())
        
        self.label.setText(f"Ответ: {result}")

    def delen(self):
        result = int(self.lineedit.text()) / int(self.lineedit2.text())
        
        self.label.setText(f"Ответ: {result}")

    def umn(self):
        result = int(self.lineedit.text()) * int(self.lineedit2.text())
        
        self.label.setText(f"Ответ: {result}")

    def clear(self):
        self.lineedit.clear()
        self.lineedit2.clear()


    def one(self):
        if self.lineedit.setFocus():
            self.lineedit.insert("1")
        if self.lineedit2.setFocus():
            self.lineedit2.insert("1")


    def two(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("2")
        #self.lineedit2.setText("2")
        print(2)

    def three(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("3")
        #self.lineedit2.setText("3")
        print(3)

    def four(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("4")
       #self.lineedit2.setText("4")
        print(4)

    def five(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("5")
        #self.lineedit2.setText("5")
        print(5)

    def six(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("6")
        #self.lineedit2.setText("6")
        print(6)

    def seven(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("7")
        #self.lineedit2.setText("7")
        print(7)

    def eight(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("8")
        #self.lineedit2.setText("8")
        print(8)

    def nine(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("9")
        #self.lineedit2.setText("9")
        print(9)

    def zero(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("0")
        #self.lineedit2.setText("0")
        print(0)



    def changeEvent(self, e):
        if e.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowStateChange:
            if self.isMinimized():
                print("Окно свернуто")
            elif self.isMaximized():
                print("Окно развернуто")
            elif self.isActiveWindow():
                print("Окно в фокусе")
        return QtWidgets.QWidget.changeEvent(self, e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `if self.lineedit.hasFocus():`

Answer (score 0):

> void [**QApplication::focusChanged**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qapplication.html#focusChanged)(QWidget *old, QWidget *now)
>
> Этот сигнал испускается, когда виджет, который имеет фокус клавиатуры, изменился со old на now, т.е. когда пользователь нажал клавишу табуляции, щелкнул виджет или изменил активное окно.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Калькулятор")
        self.resize(450, 200)
        
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("calculator.png"))
        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.grid)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Ответ:")
        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("-")
        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("+")
        self.btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("/")
        self.btn4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("*")
        self.btn5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("1")
        self.btn6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("2")
        self.btn7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("3")
        self.btn8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("4")
        self.btn9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("5")
        self.btn10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("6")
        self.btn11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("7")
        self.btn12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("8")
        self.btn13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("9")
        self.btn14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("0")
        self.btn16 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("C")
        self.btn15 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("**")
# !!!
        self.lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineedit.setObjectName('lineedit')                      # +++ 
        self.lineedit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineedit2.setObjectName('lineedit2')                    # +++ 

        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 9, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lineedit, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lineedit2, 0 ,1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn1, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn2 , 1 , 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn3 , 2, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn4 , 2, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn15 , 3 , 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn16 ,3 , 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn5 ,4 , 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn6 , 4  ,1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn7 , 5 ,0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn8 , 5 ,1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn9 , 6 ,0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn10, 6 ,1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn11 , 7 ,0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn12, 7 ,1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn13, 8 ,0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn14, 8, 1)
        
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.minus)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.plus)
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(self.delen)
        self.btn4.clicked.connect(self.umn)
        self.btn5.clicked.connect(self.one)
        self.btn6.clicked.connect(self.two)
        self.btn7.clicked.connect(self.three)
        self.btn8.clicked.connect(self.four)
        self.btn9.clicked.connect(self.five)
        self.btn10.clicked.connect(self.six)
        self.btn11.clicked.connect(self.seven)
        self.btn12.clicked.connect(self.eight)
        self.btn13.clicked.connect(self.nine)
        self.btn14.clicked.connect(self.zero)
        self.btn16.clicked.connect(self.clear)
        self.btn15.clicked.connect(self.qwe)

        self.btn1.setShortcut("Ctrl+1")
        self.btn2.setShortcut("Ctrl+2")
        self.btn3.setShortcut("Ctrl+3")
        self.btn4.setShortcut("Ctrl+4")
        self.btn16.setShortcut("Ctrl+5")
        self.btn15.setShortcut("Ctrl+6")
# !!!        
        self.lineEditFocused = None                                      # +++ 
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(700, self._focusChanged)                # +++ 
# !!!
    def _focusChanged(self):                                             # +++ 
        app.focusChanged.connect(self.on_focusChaned)                    # +++ 

    def qwe(self):
        result = int(self.lineedit.text()) ** int(self.lineedit2.text())
        self.label.setText(f"Ответ: {result}")

    def minus(self):
        result = int(self.lineedit.text()) - int(self.lineedit2.text())
        self.label.setText(f"Ответ: {result}")

    def plus(self):
        result = int(self.lineedit.text()) + int(self.lineedit2.text())
        self.label.setText(f"Ответ: {result}")

    def delen(self):
        result = int(self.lineedit.text()) / int(self.lineedit2.text())
        self.label.setText(f"Ответ: {result}")

    def umn(self):
        result = int(self.lineedit.text()) * int(self.lineedit2.text())
        self.label.setText(f"Ответ: {result}")

    def clear(self):
        self.lineedit.clear()
        self.lineedit2.clear()

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def on_focusChaned(self, widget):
        self.lineEditFocused = widget            # <-- Это будет объект QLineEdit

    def one(self):
        #print(f'one(self): {self.lineEditFocused}') 

        if self.lineEditFocused.objectName() in ['lineedit', 'lineedit2']: # +++
            self.lineEditFocused.setText('1')                              # +++ 

        ''' 
        if self.lineedit.setFocus():
            self.lineedit.insert("1")
        if self.lineedit2.setFocus():
            self.lineedit2.insert("1")
        '''
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def two(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("2")
        #self.lineedit2.setText("2")
        print(2)

    def three(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("3")
        #self.lineedit2.setText("3")
        print(3)

    def four(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("4")
       #self.lineedit2.setText("4")
        print(4)

    def five(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("5")
        #self.lineedit2.setText("5")
        print(5)

    def six(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("6")
        #self.lineedit2.setText("6")
        print(6)

    def seven(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("7")
        #self.lineedit2.setText("7")
        print(7)

    def eight(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("8")
        #self.lineedit2.setText("8")
        print(8)

    def nine(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("9")
        #self.lineedit2.setText("9")
        print(9)

    def zero(self):
        #self.lineedit.setText("0")
        #self.lineedit2.setText("0")
        print(0)

    def changeEvent(self, e):
        if e.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowStateChange:
            if self.isMinimized():
                print("Окно свернуто")
            elif self.isMaximized():
                print("Окно развернуто")
            elif self.isActiveWindow():
                print("Окно в фокусе")
        return QtWidgets.QWidget.changeEvent(self, e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @КаналкланаLesikalEmpire что  не так?